# how to make a div toggle background-position "onclick" while keeping hover

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to make a DIV to show highlighted image on hover, but keep showing highlighted when clicked, and when clicked again it should revert back to how it was.

So far i have succeeded with hover and showing highlighted image when clicked.
But i am not able to revert it back to normal hover when clicked again.

Here's my code:

**JSFiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/muLzfzfu/

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="fav"></div>
  <div class="label">Option #1</div>
  <br clear="all" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="fav"></div>
  <div class="label">Option #2</div>
  <br clear="all" />
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="fav"></div>
  <div class="label">Option #3</div>
  <br clear="all" />
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.fav {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:top;
    width:26px;
    height:25px;
    float:left;
    background-image:url(http://highviewsweb.com/temp/fav.png);
    cursor:pointer;
}
.fav:hover {
    background-position:bottom;
}
.row{
    background-color:#eee;
    margin-bottom:1px;
}
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fav').click(function(){
        $(this).css('background-position-y','0%');
        if($(this).css('background-position-y') == '0%'){
            $(this).css('background-position-y','100%');
        } else {
            $(this).css('background-position-y','0%');
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve this, one would be to create an active state class for your favourite buttons and have this use the same styles as `.fav:hover`. Then simply toggle the class:

**CSS**

```
.fav:hover, .fav-active {
    background-position:bottom;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.fav').click(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.toggleClass('fav-active');
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/muLzfzfu/4/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the 3rd line:

```
//$(this).css('background-position-y','0%');
```

The IF always evaluates to true.

And add this css:

```
background-position-y: 0%;
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/muLzfzfu/3/

Answer (score 0):

And what about using:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.fav').click(function(){
        $(this).toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

and adding in your css file:

```
.fav.active{ background-position: bottom; }
```

?